# Vagrant chef provision specific recipe rather than default

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo

I have a sample VagrantFile that looks like the following:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-6.7"
    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
        chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
    end
end
```

This successfully provisions the box with 'build-essential' using the default recipe at `build-essential\recipes\default.rb`.

How could I specify in the vagrant file that it should use a non default recipe in that cookbook, for example `build-essential\recipes\customised_default.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error (and reading more chef documentation):

```
chef.add_recipe "build-essential::customised_default"
```